# How to mock value for axios in serverless-jest-plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, jestjs

I have a problem to create test in serverless lambda in aws.
I have one handler in serverless I using axios request to get information.

Code like below.

```js
module.exports = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.API_URL,
  headers
})
```

```js
module.exports = (event) => {
  const url = process.env.API_URL

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: `${url}`
  }

  return request(options)
    .then((result) => {
     return {
       200,
       body: JSON.stringify({
          200,
          result.data
       }),
       {}
       }
     })
    .catch((error) => {
     return {
       400,
       body: JSON.stringify({
          400,
          `resource not found`
       }),
       {}
       }
     })
}
```

I would like to create a test for this handler without axios request to outside so I want to create a mock value JSON for this. because I use this test in local and GitLab ci.

My question

1 How to create mock value for this request without request to outside.

2 Please give me some info or tutorial or a simple code.

Thank you, helper.

Comment: What's `Response` and `resolveError`?  Please provide the minimal, completed code.

Comment: @slideshowp2 I already updated.

Comment: Your code has syntax errors.

Comment: Have you tried jest.mockResolvedValue?

Comment: @Coco I want to create a mock JSON value instead of request API.

Comment: you can  
> import axios from 'axios';  
and
> jest.mock('axios');
and mock your json value like this:  
> axios.get.mockResolvedValue(payload);

Comment: Hi @Coco I got errot `Error: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80` when I using const axios = require('axios') and jest.mock('axios')

Comment: @Mrempty Then mock function is not called but the actual implementation.